# Jasper Report pass one object to JRDataSource

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jasper-reports

I need to pass just one object to my jasper report page.When I send list it works but when I send one object like following code it doesnt work.
How I can do it ?

**Code of report maker method :**

```
// generatePdfReport
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/report/{id}")
public ModelAndView generatePdfReport(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id, ModelAndView modelAndView)
        throws JRException {

    LOG.info("--------------generate PDF report----------");

    Map<String, Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    java.util.List<Node> nodeList = new ArrayList<Node>();
    JRDataSource JRdataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(nodeList);

    Node node = nodeService.getOne(id);
    nodeList.add(node);
    parameterMap.put("datasource", JRdataSource);

    // pdfReport bean has ben declared in the spring configuration
    modelAndView = new ModelAndView("pdfReport", parameterMap);

    return modelAndView;

}
```

Comment: `I need to pass just one object to my jasper report page` - What do you mean? Do you want to show only one Bean? Your question is unclear

Comment: I mean that when i send list it work , but when i send one object it doesnt work  :/

Comment: You should post the small *jrxml* + the snippet of code which builds the report (passing parameters, datasource, connection) to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem with following codes,thanks to all :

```
// generatePdfReport single node
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/report/{id}")
public ModelAndView generatePdfReport(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id, ModelAndView modelAndView)
        throws JRException {

    LOG.info("--------------generate PDF report----------");

    Map<String, Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    java.util.List<Node> nodeList = new ArrayList<Node>();
    nodeList.add(nodeService.getOne(id));

    JRDataSource JRdataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(nodeList);

    parameterMap.put("datasource", JRdataSource);

    // pdfReport bean has ben declared in the spring configuration
    modelAndView = new ModelAndView("nodesReport_PDF", parameterMap);

    return modelAndView;

}
```

Comment: What is a difference? To swap out 2 lines of code? Looks like JRBeanCollectionDataSource makes a copy of List, right? Did you check it?

Comment: Yeah,  they are different . I added node object to my list before setting datasource

Answer (score -1):

Below my working code, hope will help.

```
Map <String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
parameters.put("receipt_name", "Test name");
parameters.put("contacts2", "Test 2");
String filename_report = "notary_report_commercial.jasper";

try {
        JasperPrint  jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(filename_report,parameters,new JREmptyDataSource());

         jasperPrint.setOrientation(OrientationEnum.PORTRAIT);


      JasperPrintManager.printReport(jasperPrint, false);
} catch(Exception ex) {

}
```

Comment: What is this? How it can help?